# Send an automatic email from within Excel if a formula value met a condition

Tags: excel, vba, email

Could you please help me to automatically send an email from Excel only when the formula value in column M (=IF(VAL.EMPTY(K15);"";MAX(K15-Today();0))**>200**. Unfortunately the Sheet1 code triggers the email code if the condition is met (>200) in formula value cell in column M if the date in column K is altered manually or by writing manually Not Sent in column N. Instead my goal would be:
1) to understand why this code in sheet1 doesn't send the email automatically as supposed to do (the only thing it does is to put Sent in column N without sending the email. This make me think that this code works)
2) to find the way to send the email automatically without changing anything manually in the cells in my sheet1.

```
          H           I        J             K           L          M           N
       Date       Score  Description      Next Due     Status   Days till
                                                                expiration      
15    28/09/2017   13    Medium Risk     25/07/2018     Valid      284         Sent 
16    11/10/2017   13    Medium Risk     10/08/2018     Valid      300         Sent 

'Sheet1 (FormulaValueChange)

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Dim FormulaRange As Range
Dim NotSentMsg As String
Dim MyMsg As String
Dim SentMsg As String
Dim MyLimit As Double

NotSentMsg = "Not Sent"
SentMsg = "Sent"

'Above the MyLimit value it will run the macro
MyLimit = 200

'Set the range with the Formula that you want to check
Set FormulaRange = Me.Range("M15:M16")

On Error GoTo EndMacro:
For Each FormulaCell In FormulaRange.Cells
    With FormulaCell
        If IsNumeric(.Value) = False Then
            MyMsg = "Not numeric"
        Else
            If .Value > MyLimit Then
                MyMsg = SentMsg
                If .Offset(0, 1).Value = NotSentMsg Then
                    Call Mail_with_outlook1(FormulaCell)
                End If
            Else
                MyMsg = NotSentMsg
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        .Offset(0, 1).Value = MyMsg
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End With
Next FormulaCell

ExitMacro:
Exit Sub

EndMacro:
Application.EnableEvents = True

MsgBox "Some Error occurred." _
     & vbLf & Err.Number _
     & vbLf & Err.Description

End Sub

'Mail Code 

Option Explicit

Public FormulaCell As Range

Sub Mail_with_outlook1(FormulaCell As Range)

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim strto As String, strcc As String, strbcc As String
Dim strsub As String, strbody As String

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

strto = "tom@something.abc"
strcc = ""
strbcc = ""
strsub = "Assessement reminders"
strbody = "Thanks a lot"
With OutMail
    .To = strto
    .CC = strcc
    .BCC = strbcc
    .Subject = strsub
    .Body = strbody
    'You can add a file to the mail like this
    '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
    .Display    ' or use .Send
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: put in breakpoints into your code and trace the execution as it progresses .... get rid of the `on error` line. it masks errors

Comment: I have done it and it seems it works still ok

Comment: So it doesn't make any difference but the email it is not yet sent out

Comment: are you saying that `OutMail.Display` gets executed, but you do not see the email message?

Comment: I think It gets executed as I can see in column N "Sent" instead of "Not numeric" or "Not sent".  I guess it gets executed but it doesn't display the email message.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

```
Sub Mail_small_Text_Outlook()
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "Hi there" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
              "Cell A1 is changed" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 2" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 3" & vbNewLine & _
              "This is line 4"

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = strbody
        'You can add a file like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Display   'or use .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/bmail9.htm